# To Rollback or Not to Rollback

Tags: discussion, rollbacks

Consider the following events:

- A relatively new user asks a question
- The question gets 2-3 downvotes
- The OP gets irritated by the downvotes and changes their question to something like "this site sucks"

In this case, is it appropriate to rollback the edit? Or should it be flagged for moderator attention / be closed? (A recent example is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20886885/1438393)).

Should we rollback the offensive edits to the most meaningful revision?

Comment: Absolutely yes and while doing it editing and improving is ideal.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you should roll back vandalism edits.

However, do not get into a rollback war with the OP. Do try to educate the user in the comments (politely), and leave any conflict handling to the moderators.

Several rollbacks on a post will trigger an automatic moderator flag, but you are welcome to flag a post manually to bring it to the attention of the diamond brigade too.

For your specific example, the community already stepped in and [rolled back the vandalism](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20886885/revisions), and someone left a [great encouraging comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886885/how-can-i-print-the-same-value-that-i-generated-using-array-rand-after-using-i#comment31345921_20886885) too.

Comment: I'm the one who did the [rollback](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20886885/2), by the way. I just wanted to know if it's appropriate or not. The question was edited within the 5 minutes period, so it wasn't possible to do a 'real' roll back. Google cache helped with that! :)

Comment: *vanity upvote*

Comment: @AmalMurali: Ah, I missed that specific edit; I was referring to the later rollbacks. :-) Good on you grabbing the Google Cache copy, though!

Comment: [Excellent comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886885/how-can-i-print-the-same-value-that-i-generated-using-array-rand-after-using-i#comment31345921_20886885), @jadarnel27! I think we need more users like you :)

Comment: Thanks, @Amal.  I just happened to have the time to try and be welcoming.  Many other users would surely do the same =)  That guy might be a lost cause, but there's no harm in trying.